# Operador OR entre varios strings

Tags: c#

tengo un problema al comparar varios strings.

```
if (IDObjectDown1 == "R1" || IDObjectDown2 == "R1" || IDObjectDown3 == "R1" || IDObjectDown4 == "R1" || IDObjectDown5 == "R1" || IDObjectDown6 == "R1")
        {
            WebClient D = new WebClient();
            string U = "https://.....";
            if (DownloadC == 1)
            {
                Funcion1 = U;
            }
            else if (DownloadC == 2)
            {
                Funcion2 = U;
            }
            else if (DownloadC == 3)
            {
                Funcion3 = U;
            }
            else if (DownloadC == 4)
            {
                Funcion4 = U;
            }
            else if (DownloadC == 5)
            {
                Funcion5 = U;
            }
            else if (DownloadC == 6)
            {
                Funcion6 = U;
            }
```

Esto sirve para descargar unos objetos, primero identifica de las 6 zonas si el objeto es (por ejemplo) R1, Una vez identificado procede a descargarlo y dependiendo de la zona se ejecuta la descarga en una funcion diferente (es necesario).

El problema es que la primera vez funciona bien, cuando voy a descargar el segundo objeto:

```
if (IDObjectDown1 == "R2" || IDObjectDown2 == "R2" || IDObjectDown3 == "R2" || IDObjectDown4 == "R2" || IDObjectDown5 == "R2" || IDObjectDown6 == "R2")
        {
            WebClient D = new WebClient();
            string U = "https://.....";
            if (DownloadC == 1)
            {
                Funcion1 = U;
            }
            else if (DownloadC == 2)
            {
                Funcion2 = U;
            }
            else if (DownloadC == 3)
            {
                Funcion3 = U;
            }
            else if (DownloadC == 4)
            {
                Funcion4 = U;
            }
            else if (DownloadC == 5)
            {
                Funcion5 = U;
            }
            else if (DownloadC == 6)
            {
                Funcion6 = U;
            }
```

Me descarga el primero en la zona 2 por que detecta que el IDObjectDown1 es R1 y se salta el R2.

Si pongo el IDObjectDown del 6 al 1, funciona bien, hasta que quiero agrega otra descarga a la zona 1, coge el objeto de descarga de la zona 6 y la descarga tambien en la zona 1.

PD: No quiero tener que poner el string con la URL de descarga en cada DownloadC.

Visual Studio 2013, Winforms.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿El problema son los OR concatenados o la descarga de objetos?

Comment: Los OR, la descarga funciona, descarga el archivo, pero no el correcto por culpa de los OR(creo).
Descarga siempre el objeto1 por que al estar antes de la descarga del objeto 2 pues coje la url del primer objeto.

Comment: Entonces como es tu codigo completo? porque no se entiende el problema...

Comment: Haber si asi me entienden:
Tengo 6 zonas de descarga y varios objetos de descarga. Cuando descargo el primer objeto, de inicia la descarga en la zona 1, con el objeto R1, Si quiero descargar el objeto 2, se descarga el objeto 1 en la zona 2, por que el objeto 2 tambien puede ser descargado en la zona 1 y al estar primero el objeto 1 antes del 2, descarga el objeto 1 en todas las zonas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

porque no usas linq

en vez de hacer un or si existen en Objeto un R1

los IDObjeto1..2..3 los adicionas en un List<>
y llamas un where containd

```
List<ObjetoDown> ObjetoDescargado = new List<ObjetoDown>(); //entendiendo que objetoDown tiene IDObjectDownX y "R1"

 var ExistIDOject = ObjetoDescargado.Where(o => o.IDObject.Contains("R1"));
 if (ExistIDOject.Count() > 0)
        {
            WebClient D = new WebClient();
            string U = "https://.....";
            if (DownloadC == 1)
            {
                Funcion1 = U;
            }
            else if (DownloadC == 2)
            {.................
```

esto como haciendo referencia de la sentencia select.... where  in("R1")

Comment: Me sirvio, muchas gracias :)